# Git, how to find out the number of commits made in a specific month

Tags: git

How can I find out the number of commits made in a specific month, without using **before/after** in `git log --after={somedate} --before={somedate} | wc -l` ? (also I don't know if this is correct)

Comment: You need to add `--oneline` to your `git log` so that wc counts the lines correctly

Comment: What do you mean "without using before/after" in git log?

Comment: Use `git rev-list --count`, but note that this is really the same thing as `git log`, it's just more conveniently packaged for automation.

Comment: @Trent I want to find out for a specific month, lets say January, so I used --after={2020-01-01} --before={2020-01-31} and if there is another way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with the Git log output, we can specify a date range using the `--since` and `--until` command-line options.

For example, to get the commits from April 2020, you can use the following:

```
git log --since "APR 1 2020" --until "MAY 1 2020"
```

We can get the number of commits by counting the lines, but we must ensure that only one-line is printed per commit. This is possible using the `--pretty=oneline` git log formatter:

```
 git log --pretty=oneline
```

Finally, we can count the number of lines by piping our git log output from stdout to the `wc` shell executable. By default, this executable will count the number of characters, but can be configured to count lines using the `-l` command-line option:

```
wc -l
```

### Answer

We configure git log to print the commits from a specified date range and ensure one-line is printed per commit. Then, we feed the log into a line counter and get our results:

```
 git log --since "APR 1 2020" --until "MAY 1 2020" --pretty=oneline | wc -l
```

Comment: Thanks! you answer is correct! I noticed that in order to get the whole month, it should be until the first day of the next month.

Comment: Good catch, @Orion! I've updated the answer to use `--unit "MAY 1 2020"` as you've suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write in number of months that have passed in `--since` and `--until`.

```
git log --since="2 month ago" --until="1 month ago" --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%ar,%s'
```

- **current month: April: so all commits from 1 February 2020 to 31 March 2020**

Or to use date format with numbers like this:

```
git log --since="2020-01-01" --until="2020-03-31" --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%ar,%s'
```

- **commits from 1 Januar 2020 until 31 March 2020**

*Explaining the several option from the git command:*

> - **%h** Shows the git commit-hash
> - **%an** Shows the name from the commit author
> - **%ar** Shows creation date of the commit
> - **%s** Shows topic of commit (comment from commit command)